# Не отправляется запрос с сервера

Tags: веб-программирование, angular5, angular

Проект имеет API на сервере api.domain.info и сам клиент на domain.info. Клиент написан на Angular 5. Суть вопроса: при запуске приложения на 4200 порту на локальной машине - запросы работают нормально
[image: Успешный запрос]

но как только я делаю `ng build --prod` 
и размещаю результат на сервере - запрос просто не проходит
[image]

Comment: В консоли браузера должен быть написан нормальный текст ошибки

Comment: @andreymal `The page at 'https://domain.info/login' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://api.domain.info/login'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.`
это значит надо на API вешать SSL?

Comment: Да, надо. . . .